# Hudson File SCM Plugin

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

We use Hudson CI as our build tool , when we refer to file system in the same server machine,where  Hudson is running ,there was no problem.

But when we used File SCM plugin to point to file system in remote machine with all the read/write previleges ,it cannot check-out and failed with below error.

```
FATAL: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:358)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.iterateFiles(FileUtils.java:404)
    at hudson.plugins.filesystem_scm.FolderDiff.getNewOrModifiedFiles(FolderDiff.java:104)
    at hudson.plugins.filesystem_scm.RemoteFolderDiff$CheckOut.invoke(RemoteFolderDiff.java:94)
    at hudson.plugins.filesystem_scm.RemoteFolderDiff$CheckOut.invoke(RemoteFolderDiff.java:88)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.plugins.filesystem_scm.FSSCM.checkout(FSSCM.java:123)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1483)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:507)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1366)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
```

Comment: Can you post the values that you have set in the "Source Code Management" and "Build Triggers" sections of your job configuration ?

Comment: Build Triggers POLL SCM :  */30 * * * *  , Source Code management: FileSystemPath: \\remoteserver\d$\source\

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things I can think of based on your configuration - please note that i'm not a Windows expert though.

1. Is your Hudson server running on Windows ?  If not, the \remoteserver\d$\source\  format for the file system path won't work.
2. Does the user running Hudson have access to the remote file path \remoteserver\d$\source\  ?

Comment: Yes ,it is running in winodows ,the running user have  access to remote source

Answer (score 1):

I got this solved ,after i run the Hudson service with user id ,which has got access to the remote server location.